# Custom URL Scheme Issue For Windows

Tags: windows, web-applications, url-scheme

I have added a URL scheme to redirect to an application on the click of a button. Right now what happens is the application is getting crashed on the click of the button(Created a website and within that on clicking button i have to redirect to a windows desktop app). I have gone through event viewer logs and identified that this application is searching for some xpa's in "C:\Users\User001\Desktop" where as the application is in "C:\TestApp\bin". I have added this path even in environment system variable "PATH" as "C:\TestApp\bin". Can anyone help me to resolve the issue? I would like to redirect the control to already opened instance of the windows desktop app on the click of this button.

Comment: anybody who has worked in this ?